# Problems while committing datagrid's deleted rows to the data source

Tags: c#, wpf, database, datagrid

i made this little application to play with DbConnection classes. My dbConnect class retrieve, among other things, a DataTable object filled through a suitable DataAdapter implementing runtime generated update, insert and delete commands via parametrized queries. Then, i'm binding a wpf DataGrid.DataContext to such table to allow for data manipulation. The user can delete, update and/or insert any number of rows, then the changes can be committed to the underlying database clicking on a button control ('Update').
My problem is that the deleted rows are not reflected on the database as inserted/modified ones. Here is some code:

Xaml Datagrid ItemSource Binding:

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}" ... />
```

code behind:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName = cbox.SelectedItem as string))
{
    table = _dbc.getData( tableName );
    dataGrid1.Items.Refresh();
    dataGrid1.DataContext = table.DefaultView;
    table.DefaultView.ListChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventHandler(dataView_ListChanged);  // Needed to enable the 'Update' button to, well, update the Database

    if (table.Rows.Count == 0) warnMsg = "The selected table (" + tableName.ToUpper() + ") is empty.";
}
```

The listChanged event handler simply enables/disables the 'Update' button if changes are made to the datagrid/datatable's rows while the button logic calls a public method (committChanges( DataRow[] rows) of the DbConnect class (_dbc, here) which in turn simply calls the (DataAdapter) dapt.Update() method.

Notice that in a previous version of the dbConnect class, i was hooking the DataTable's RowChanging and RowDeleting events to committChanges method for single rows update (added, deleted or modified) and all changes were reflected into the db successfully, so the logic itself should be fine. Any input will do. Thanks.

Comment: ok, i think i found something. The Update method of DataAdapter accepts an array of DataRows (the modified rows of the DataTable), the rows of the datatable you get when calling the GetChanges() method. Based on the DataRowState each of them represents an addition, a modification, or a deletion to commit into the database. So i was sending the DataTable.GetChanges().Select() DataRow[] to the update method to do the trick. But it seems that such array no longer holds original DataRowState, probably resulting in a default behaviour from the DataAdapter Update method (maybe the update behaviour).

Comment: As i thought. Question solved.